# Refactoring Help for main class or test code coverage

Tags: apex, code-coverage, apextestrunresult

I'm trying to refactor the following code.I'm trying to figure out how to refactor this code OR if anyone have a good way to do code coverage for this.

My issue is that, in dev, the code coverage is only the if-else statement for '%DEV%' and the rest are not covered in dev because its only getting the URL base url for the respective environment.
In QA, the code coverage is only the if-else statement for '%QA%' and the rest are not covered.
So on and so forth...

The custom labels contain the following values.

System.Label.DevSB-->dev

System.Label.QASB-->qa

System.Label.StageSB-->stage

System.Label.IntSB-->stage

Our Salesforce Sandbox Instances and URLs are as follow.

mycompany--dev20.my.salesforce.com --> dev

mycompany--qa20.my.salesforce.com --> qa

mycompany--stage.my.salesforce.com --> stage

mycompany--int.my.salesforce.com --> stage environment but for integration purposes

mycompany.my.salesforce.com --> prod

Essentially we have this method and if this method is executed in our dev environment (mycompany--dev20.my.salesforce.com) it should return '%Dev%', and if its executed in qa environment (mycompany--qa20.my.salesforce.com), then it should return '%QA%' so on and so forth....

```
public static String getSandboxName(){
    
    if(URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().getHost().containsIgnoreCase(System.Label.DevSB)){
        return '%Dev%';
    } else if(URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().getHost().containsIgnoreCase(System.Label.QASB)){
        return '%QA%';
    } else if(URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().getHost().containsIgnoreCase(System.Label.StageSB) || URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().getHost().containsIgnoreCase(System.Label.IntSB)){
        return '%Stage%';
    } else {
        return '%PROD%';
    }
}
```

This is my test classes but unfortunately, it is not working.

```
static testMethod void testGetSandboxNameDEV(){

    String actualSandboxName;
    PageReference pageRef;

    pageRef = new PageReference('https://mycompany--dev20.my.salesforce.com');
    Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);
    actualSandboxName = MyClass.getSandboxName();
    System.Debug('baseUrl-->' + URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().getHost());
    System.assertEquals('%Dev%', actualSandboxName);
    
}

static testMethod void testGetSandboxNameQA(){

    String actualSandboxName;
    PageReference pageRef;

    pageRef = new PageReference('https://mycompany--qa20.my.salesforce.com');
    pageRef.setRedirect(true);
    Test.setCurrentPageReference(pageRef);
    actualSandboxName = MyClass.getSandboxName();
    System.Debug('baseUrl-->' + URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().getHost());
    System.assertEquals('%QA%', actualSandboxName);
    
}   


static testMethod void testGetSandboxNameSTAGE(){

        String actualSandboxName;
        PageReference pageRef;

        pageRef = new PageReference('https://mycompany--stage.my.salesforce.com');
        pageRef.setRedirect(true);
        Test.setCurrentPageReference(pageRef);
        actualSandboxName = MyClass.getSandboxName();
        System.Debug('baseUrl-->' + URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().getHost());
        System.assertEquals('%Stage', actualSandboxName);
        
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't override the return value of `URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl()` in a test class.

There's two possible approaches here. One is to factor out the code that calls that method into a separate code unit so that you can utilize dependency injection to control its return value. But that seems like overkill here. There's a much simpler option: refactor your code so that it doesn't use conditional logic you can't cover:

```
public static String getSandboxName() {
    Map<String, String> urlMap = new Map<String, String>{
        System.Label.DevSB => '%Dev%',
        System.Label.QASB => '%QA%',
        System.Label.StageSB => '%Stage%',
        System.Label.IntSB => '%Stage%',
        'salesforce' => '%PROD%'
    };

    for (String k : urlMap.keys()) {
        if (URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().getHost().containsIgnoreCase(k)) {
            return urlMap.get(k);
        }
    }
}
```

(Disclaimer, typed here and not tested).

That should allow you to get full coverage regardless of which environment the test runs in because every branch is executed.

Comment: This code snippet helped! Thank you